# Copy files from multiple folders. [BASH]

Tags: bash

Hello Stackoverflowers,

I'm new to StackOverflow, and I have a qeustion I couldn't find so I hope anyone can help me out.

I have to make a backup script for my internship, which copies multiple files from multiple folders. All I need to know is how to go through all the folders in a directory..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have `find`  installed its pretty easy:

```
$parentdir="./"

#get all subdirectories in parentdir folder
for folderpath in $(find $parentdir -type d -iname "*" -not -path "$parentdir")
do
    #remove parentdir path to be left with the actual dir name
    foldername="${folder/$parentdir/}"
done
```

what the find command does:

- `find` > the command
- `$parentdir` > the path to look in
- `-type d` > only get directories
- `-iname "*"` > get EVERYTHING in dirpath and all its subdirectories
- `-not -path $parentdir` > exclude the parentdir from the found directories

Comment: Thank you so much man! Helped me out!